# How to disable grouping search results by size in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

How can I disable this stupid grouping of search results in Windows 7? It drives me crazy. I really like Windows 7 but setting this as default is naerly idiotic. But having no obvious way to change it is idiotic in incredibly epic way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the backgorund of Explorer and go to `Group by` => `Size`. That will toggle the setting.

Comment: Holy crap! Never right-clicked the blank space. I knew it would be that easy but couldn't find the option. Thanks! :D